# When using (Bootstrap) <Dropdown > arrowmoves its position to slightly up when clicked CSS/Bootstrap/ReactJS

Tags: dom

i am struggling with an issue when using  `<Dropdown.Toggle>`, actually the arrow moves its position slightly up when clicked, i have spend quite a bit time and tweaked few things inorder to make its position fixed but it remains the same , any suggestions/thoughts please.

**Update-1** the original issue is resolved when i set the `height=0px` under the <Dropdown.Toggle> but now the menu that apperas after i click it appears just after the arrow below but i was expecting it to start after some padding/margin, any thoughts please

-`Snippet` from `ReactJS`

```
  return (
    <nav className="header">
 <ul>
        <li>
     <Dropdown id="dropdownbasic" as={ButtonGroup} style={{ marginTop: "5px", position: "relative", float: "left", top: "13px" }}>
    <Button .......> </Button>
      <Dropdown.Toggle
                  className="signinDropdown"
                  split
                  variant="success"
                  aria-expanded="false"
// below i added the height it solved my first issue and the arrow is now still all the time
                   style={{ "height":"0px", background: "none", borderStyle: "none", outline: "none !important" }}
                />
    
                <Dropdown.Menu>
                  <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
                  <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
)
```

-`Snippet` from `CSS` file

````
```
// added the below css but still the menu starts just below the arrow
    #dropdownbasic  > :second-child{

 top:158px;
padding-top: "13px";

}

.signinDropdown:focus,
signinDropdown.focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  
}
````

Comment: I guess the drop-down is pushing the arrow up, set a fixed height to the trigger

Comment: THanks Ainz, it does solve the problem but then i got another problem that the menu starts just below the arrow, i initially put the settings to start the menu bar with a gap. i have tried to do like `Dropdown(id) >Dropdown.Menu:first-child` but it doesnt help either. i have updated the code above. any thoughts please